# Make a single variable reactive on the server with Meteor

Tags: javascript, sockets, meteor

I have a TCP socket on the server where I monitor a connection variable. I want to publish this to the client so they can know the state of the TCP client. This is the server-side part of my package.

```
let Cylon = {};
Cylon._connected = false;

function setConnectionStatus (socket, event) {
  socket._connected = event === 'connect';
  this._connected = this._messages.connected && this._commands._connected;
  this._connected ? this.emit('connect') : this.emit('close');
}

Cylon._commands = net.connect(process.env.CONNECTION);
Cylon._messages = net.connect(process.env.CONNECTION);

Cylon._messages.addListener('connect', setConnectionStatus.bind(Cylon, Cylon._messages, 'connect'));
Cylon._commands.addListener('connect', setConnectionStatus.bind(Cylon, Cylon._commands, 'connect'));
Cylon._messages.addListener('close', setConnectionStatus.bind(Cylon, Cylon._messages, 'close'));
Cylon._commands.addListener('close', setConnectionStatus.bind(Cylon, Cylon._commands, 'close'));
```

The object is also exposed on the client, but without the TCP sockets. I want to publish the `Cylon._connected` to the client object and update it so that it could be viewed on the client. Eg:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type command here" {{#if not Cylon._connected}}disabled="true"{{/if}}>
```

Is this possible with meteor?

Comment: can't you just use `Meteor.status()` in the meteor API?  http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_status

Comment: That would be the DDP connection, but this is a TCP connection with sockets